# .net core 2.0 tests - how to store settings in test projects?

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, azure-devops

I need to store connection strings and other settings in my .NET Core 2.0 integration tests (so, it's a Test project, with xUnit). How can I do this safely considering those tests run locally and in VSTS? Ideally, I need those settings separate for local environment and running on VSTS.

Comment: Not relevant at all - I'm talking about *Test* project (xUnit). It doesn't have all that.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple configuration files, such as **appsettings.json, appsettings.dev.json, appsettings.test.json**, then set the **dev** value for related environment variable and set **test** value for related variable of build.

After that replace the value in **appsettings.test.json** file through [Token Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task

Simple steps:

1. Install [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/) to your xUnit test project
2. Add **appsettings.json, appsettings.dev.json and appsettings.test.json** configuration files to project

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "OtherSettings": {
    "UserName": "name1",
    "Pass": "pass1"
  }
}
```

appsettings.dev.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=dev;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "OtherSettings": {
    "UserName": "devname1",
    "Pass": "pass1"
  }
}
```

appsettings.test.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=#{testDev}#;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "OtherSettings": {
    "UserName": "#{testName}#",
    "Pass": "pass1"
  }
}
```

3. Set Copy to **Output Directory property** of these files to **Copy if newer**.
   4: Simple test code

:

```
            [Fact]
            public void Test1()
            {
                var envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

                Console.WriteLine($"env: {envVariable}");
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                     .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envVariable}.json", optional: true)
                    .Build();
                var conn = config.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase");
                var otherSettings = config["OtherSettings:UserName"];
                Console.WriteLine(conn);
                Console.WriteLine(otherSettings);
            }
```

5. Add **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** (value: test), **testDev** and **testName** variables to build definition, you can **click the lock icon to change variable type to secret**.
6. Add **Replace Tokens task** before build task (Target files: `**\appsettings.test.json`)

Comment: I just tried that. I can't get ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value. It's always emty when I run tests locally :( How do you set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for test project (xUnit) in VS2017 ?

Comment: Just set environment variable in your machine.

Comment: You can open a new thread for the issue of the convenient way to set environment variable.

Comment: This is highly insecure.  We need a mechanism to be able to pass these via command line or some other temporal/secure mechanism so that these values don't get persisted in git.  I.e. I should be able to pass settings to the test assembly in vsts that specify the Azure KeyVault store where the rest of the settings are stored, and VSTS should store those values encrypted.